# Flash AS3, save and load data for iOs and android games

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make games for iOS and Android. How do I save data to the gadget, and also how do I load it? The data that I want to save to the user device is basically just a bunch of strings. Kindly help please.

And by the way, I'm using Flash CS6 for the game.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharedObject class should do fine for you. The attributes you write/read can be of any type (String, Array, Number, Boolean, XML, ...).

Basic example:

```
        var scores : Array        = new Array(10, 20, 30);
        var my_so  : SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myGameHighscore");
        my_so.data.scores         = scores; // set scores var to data object of SharedObject
        my_so.flush();            // writes the data instantly

        // To retreive your scores simply use getLocal again and then do something like:
        trace(my_so.data.scores[0]); // will trace first element of scores array "10"
```

Please refer to this URL: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html