# AS3/Flash/AIR/TweenLite/ Big performance issues AIR using Tweenlite scale animations

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, gsap

i have created a little game that i want to release as an app.
All went well until i stumbled on some performance issues regarding the my menu.
I use tweenlite's libary for scaling and moving animations of my menu.

When i first tried it on my Galaxy S2 it was a bit laggy (framedrops) but no big deal as it is an old phone.
However now i have the oneplus one (the fastest phone currently) and it is still dropping frames and consuming a hell lot of CPU

Now i have thougth about trying the blitmask buffer: (https://greensock.com/blitmask) but as this is not about a big picture only showing part of it, but scaling a movieclip i was wondering if this would even help.
A demo of the SWF output: http://websitekeuken.nl/demo/bloktris-app.swf

The most laggy is the starting animation or press the "uitleg" tab and then drag the item down completely to replicate that animation.

Does anyone have an idea to make this not dropping frames or at least a lot smoother?
I mean phones can currently run whole 3d games with no trouble a simple menu animation should be no problem rigth?

Things i already tried:
- lowering the FPS;
- setting render to Direct and GPU.
- covert everything to bitmap what seems to work sligthly but still not a lot of succes.
- newest compiler of the Flash CC demo

I really hope someone can help me out with this one i am stuck working 10 hours on this problem.
Thanks in advance.

I really hope someone can help me out with this one i am stuck working 10 hours on this problem.
Thanks in advance.

The Base Menu class:

```
package com.eigen.menu
{
/**
* ...
* @author matthijs
*/


// http://www.polymer-project.org/apps/topeka/


import com.greensock.BlitMask;
import com.greensock.easing.Bounce;
import com.greensock.easing.BounceIn;
import com.greensock.easing.Elastic;
import com.greensock.TimelineLite;
import fl.transitions.easing.Regular;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.errors.IllegalOperationError;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import com.greensock.TweenLite;
    import com.greensock.easing.Strong;
    import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;


// todo save inbouwen
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074092/flash-as3-save-and-load-data-for-ios-and-android-games
public class DragMenu extends MovieClip 
{
private var bounds : Rectangle;
        private var mc : MovieClip;
var startX:Number, startY:Number;
var border:MovieClip;
var menuObjects:MenuObjects;
var lockSwipe:Boolean = false;


var isTransitioningOut = false;


public function DragMenu() 
{
startX = this.x;
startY = this.y; 
        }


public function reboot()
{ 
TweenLite.killTweensOf(this);
isTransitioningOut = false;


visible = true;
alpha = 1;


this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
}


public function init(menuObjects:MenuObjects)
{
this.visible = false;
this.border = menuObjects.border;
this.menuObjects = menuObjects;
}


public function show(type:String = ""):void
{
debug("show");
reboot();


if (type == "slide")
animateInSlide();
else
animateInElastic();
}






function animateInElastic()
{
debug("animateInElastic");


x = startX
y = startY;


scaleX=0;
scaleY=0;


//var bm:BlitMask = new BlitMask(this, 300, 300, this.width, this.height, true);
//TweenLite.to(content, 30, {x:-3000, onUpdate:bm.update});


//TweenLite.to(this, 4, { scaleX:1, scaleY:1, ease:Elastic.easeOut, onUpdate:bm.update } );
TweenLite.to(this, 4, { scaleX:1, scaleY:1, ease:Elastic.easeOut } );
}


function animateOutElastic()
{
debug("animateOutElastic");


var myTimeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite();
var duration:Number = 1;


myTimeline.add(TweenLite.to(this, duration, { x:startX, y:1024 + 1024/2, alpha:0 } ),
0,
"start",
0);


myTimeline.add(transitioningOutDone, duration);


}


function animateInSlide()
{
debug("animateInSlide");


scaleX = 1;
scaleY = 1;
y = -1024 + 1024/2;
TweenLite.to(this, 2, { y:1024/2, ease:Bounce.easeOut } );
}


function animateOutSlide()
{
debug("animateOutSlide");
isTransitioningOut = true;


var myTimeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite();


var duration:Number = 2;


myTimeline.add([new TweenLite(this, 0.3, { scaleX:1, scaleY:1, ease:Regular.easeOut }),
new TweenLite(this, duration, { y:1024 + 1024 / 2, ease:Bounce.easeOut } )],
0,
"start",
0);


myTimeline.add(transitioningOutDone, duration);


}


protected function transitioningOutDone()
{
if (isTransitioningOut == false)
return;


x = startX;
y = startY;
visible = false;


isTransitioningOut = false;
}

        private function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {




if (lockSwipe)
return;


this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);


TweenLite.killTweensOf(this);
            scaleX=1;
scaleY = 1;
alpha = 1;


var rec:Rectangle =  new Rectangle(this.width/2,this.height/2-200,0,2000);
this.startDrag(false, rec);
        }




        private function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {


this.stopDrag();


TweenLite.killTweensOf(this);
scaleX=1;
scaleY = 1;


TweenLite.to(this, 4, { x:startX, y:startY, ease:Elastic.easeOut } );
        }


      function handleCollision( e:Event ):void
{
if (lockSwipe || isTransitioningOut)
return;


if(border != null && this.hitTestObject(border))
{
trace (this.name + "handleCollision");


trace("x = " + x);
trace("y = " + y);
trace("scaleX = " + scaleX);


this.stopDrag();


this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)
this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);


TweenLite.killTweensOf(this);
animateOutElastic();


switchTo();
}
}


public function switchTo():void
{
throw new IllegalOperationError("Must override Concreate Class"); 
}


protected function debug(message:String)
{
trace(this.name + " " + message);
}




  }


}
```

Comment: 3D games on mobile are possible because they are highly optimized and rendering on GPU. One thing the weak CPU of mobile devices has problem with is vector graphics as they require much CPU power to be displayed and they drop easily fps on mobile.

Comment: Have you tried setting your menu to cacheAsBitmap?  `this.cacheAsBitmap(true)`

Comment: Parcell yes i think i did however not 100% sure. now checking

Comment: Parcell yes tested it same issues

Comment: You added the cacheAsBitmap in the init()? Just checking. What about setting menuObjects to cacheAsBitmap? Does the performance degrade over time? Or is it always poor? Is this class extended or this it? Again just checking.

Comment: Adding some other points. It look s as if each of the letters for your main menu screen is a separate text field. I am wondering how many vector elements you have in this whole thing. I would attempt to make a single bitmap image in PhotoShop and import that into your project. Make as few images as you can. If you are also using text fields for all the text, then you want to make sure it is static, unless there is a good reason otherwise. You also want to make set as many MovieClips, Sprites, and TextFields use cacheAsBitmap.

Comment: Ok i did a few things like you said (everything to one big bitmap) and also set the stage quality to low, also the rendering to a bitmap seems te work better the casheAsBitmap. it runs a lot smoother now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no way to rescale a bitmap neither a vector img for a cheap amount of processing. In fact, I always avoid absolutely all rescale and fade tweens in my apps.
Setting cacheAsBitmap its not going to help, in fact, i'll be even more harmful since what you actualy do when setting cacheAsBitmap = true is telling flash that THIS bitmap is not gonna change its form neither its rotation, and then, Tween Lite goes ahead an change it every frame, causing the drawing algorithm to "unblock" the "cachedAsBitmap img", editing it, then catching its bit map again, and uploading it to the gpu.... every goddamn frame.

My advice: remove all rescale tweens, and add other cool tweens that tween light has to offer to give you hud/gui some awesome look and feel!

Comment: Thx for the help! I think this is true, it sucks though. I changed the Scale to and Y movement its a lot smoother now, however it stil has some minor performance issues when using normal Y movements. this is mostly because of the large screens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315515/air-flash-mobile-as3-lowering-resolution-or-upscaling-for-performance