# AIR/Flash mobile/As3/ lowering resolution or upscaling for performance

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

So I've got an Android/IOS Air app built in Flash CS6 (NOT using Starling or Stage3D). In the .fla, the stage size is set to 640x1024.

Now i noticed that the stage resolution does not matter that much in air for android because it looks at the display of the phone/tablet. and the adjusts it/

The problem i encounter is that my Samsung galaxy S2 performs better then my brand new oneplus one probably because the oneplus one has a way bigger resolution 1920x1080

Now with the upcoming phones starting to overkill and go up to 4K displays i was wondering if it is possible to upscale the resolution or force an max resolution. I rather have less detail in resolution and have a smooth game then a laggy game because it is forced to details you cannot see with the bare eye.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like

```
private static function handleResize() :void {
var deviceSize:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, 
    stage.stageHeight);
// adjust the gui to fit the new device resolution
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, handleResize);
// call handleResize to initialize the first time
handleResize();

// Then set quality value
if(stage.stageHeight>200 && stage.stageHeight<380){myImageQualitySwitchVar=1}
if(stage.stageHeight>380 && stage.stageHeight<680){myImageQualitySwitchVar=2}
if(stage.stageHeight>800){myImageQualitySwitchVar=3}
```

and inside your MC's you want to load image quality you want, I would created something for your image loaders like

```
if(myImageQualitySwitchVar==1){Image01.load(new URLRequest("LowQualityIMG.jpg"));}

if(myImageQualitySwitchVar==2){Image01.load(new URLRequest("MediumQualityIMG.jpg"));}

if(myImageQualitySwitchVar==3){Image01.load(new URLRequest("HighQualityIMG.jpg"));}
```

Its alot of work doing it this way but the only alternative I can think of is to just create different builds for different devices. ie. 4 builds, a phone build for devices using SDk x.x and under and phones above SDk x.x get different build.  and another 2 builds for specific tablets above and below SDK x.x.

hope this helps.

Comment: thx for the help but i dont think this will work, because it is not about the quality of the image but the problem lies in the fact that bigger phones it need to render 1920x1080 pixels in stead of 800x480. so on the exact same build the game goes smoother on the lower end phone 480p then the new phone 1080p